# Multi-dimensional array convert and path add

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array who looks something like that:
http://pastebin.com/raw/myuRm6cs

I want to convert this array to one level and add path keys, example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [path] => Niebieski|S|Bawelna
            [price] => 
            [warehouse] => 
            [send] => dst
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [path] => Niebieski|S|Poliester
            [price] => 
            [warehouse] => 
            [send] => dst
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [path] => Niebieski|S|Skora
            [price] => 
            [warehouse] => 
            [send] => dst
        )
```

--

```
    $ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($types));
    $results = array();
    foreach ($ritit as $leafValue) {
        $path = array();
        foreach (range(0, $ritit->getDepth()) as $depth) {
            $path[] = $ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->key();
        }
        $results[] = join('|', $path);
    }
```

This code create path of array but i dont know how use them to get the effect.

Comment: please paste your original array code here

Comment: its long array so i upload to pastebin because i want is my post was clear to read

Answer (score 0):

Without ArrayIterator it's very easy

```
$results = array();

foreach ($types as $k1=>$v1) 
   foreach ($v1 as $k2=>$v2) 
      foreach ($v2 as $k3=>$v3)      
         $results[] = array('parh' => $k1 . '|' . $k2 . '|' . $k3) + $v3;      

print_r($results);
```

Comment: Yes its simple, but in other case array has 2 or 4 or more levels. I want to get universal solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
$results = array();
foreach ($ritit as  $key => $leafValue) {
    $path = array();
    foreach (range(0, $ritit->getDepth()-1) as $depth) {
        $path[] = $ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->key();
        $b = $ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->current();
    }
    $b['path'] = join('|', $path);
    $results[] = $b;
}
print_r($results);
```

but there is a bug